# IF Statement regarding tax (python/html)

Tags: python, html, forms

My If statements wont give me any correct answers. Can someone have a look at them?

```
if total > 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 ==
"bC":
    print"<p>Tax: $",(total-disc)*0.12,"</p>" elif total <150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
    print "<p>Tax: $",total*0.12,"</p>" elif total > 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
    print "<p>Tax: $",float(((total-disc)+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>" elif total < 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
    print "<p>Tax: $",float((total+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>" elif total > 150 and b1 != "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC":
    print"<p>Tax: $",float((total-disc))*0.12,"</p>" elif total < 150 and b1!= "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC":
    print "<p>Tax: $",float(total)*0.12,"</p>" elif total > 150 and b1 != "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC" and
form.getvalue("giftwrap"):
    print "<p>Tax: $",float(((total-disc)+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>" elif total < 150 and b1 != "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC"
and form.getvalue("giftwrap"):
    print "<p>Tax: $",float((total+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>"
```

Heres the rest of the code, Thanks:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# print HTTP/HTML header stuff
print """Content-type: text/html

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html><head>
    <title>Order Form</title>
    </head><body>
    """

    # print HTML body using form data
    print "<h1>Profesional Painters</h1>"
    print "<h2>Customer Reciept</h2>"
    print "<p>Customer Name:", form["customerName"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>Customer Email Address:", form["customerEmail"].value, "</p>"
    print "<h2>Customer Address:</h2>"
    print "<p>Street:", form["customerAdd"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>City:", form["customerCity"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>Province:", form["customerProv"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>Postal Code:", form["customerPostal"].value, "</p>"
    print "<h2>Payment Information:</h2>"
    print "<p>Card Type:", form["type1"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>Card Number: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-", form["four4"].value, "</p>"
    print "<p>Expiry Date:", form["expirt"].value, "</p>"

    print "<h2>Products Ordered</h2>"

    q1 = int(form["quantity"].value)*2
    q2 = int(form["quantity2"].value)*1
    q3 = int(form["quantity3"].value)*150
    q4 = int(form["quantity4"].value)*3
    q5 = int(form["quantity5"].value)*10

    if form.getvalue("interior"):
        print "<p>Interior Painting quantity:", form["quantity"].value, "</p>"
        print "<p>Cost: $" ,q1, ".00</p>"

    else:
        q1 = 0
        print "<p>Interior Painting quantity: 0 <br /> Cost: $0</p>"

    if form.getvalue("exterior"):
        print "<p>Exterior Painting quantity:", form["quantity2"].value, "</p>"
        print "<p>Cost: $" ,q2, ".00</p>"

    else:
        q2 = 0
        print "<p>Exterior Painting quantity: 0 <br /> Cost: $0</p>"

    if form.getvalue("pressure"):
        print "<p>Pressure Washing quantity:", form["quantity3"].value, "</p>"
        print "<p>Cost : $" ,q3, ".00</p>"
    else:
        q3 = 0   
        print "<p>Pressure Washing quantity: 0 <br /> Cost: $0</p>"

    if form.getvalue("wood"):
        print "<p>Wood Finishing quantity:", form["quantity4"].value, "</p>"
        print "<p>Cost: $" ,int(form["quantity4"].value)*3, ".00</p>"
    else:
        q4 = 0
        print "<p>Wood Finsihing quantity: 0 <br /> Cost: $0</p>"

    if form.getvalue("spraycan"):
        print "<p>Spray Can quantity:", form["quantity5"].value, "</p>"
        print "<p>Cost: $" ,int(form["quantity5"].value)*10, ".00</p>"
    else:
        q5 = 0
        print "<p>Spray Can quantity: 0 <br /> Cost: $0</p>"

    if form.getvalue("email"):
        print "<p>An email notification will be sent to ",form["customerEmail"].value, "</p>"

    total = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5
    print "<p>Total Cost of goods purchased is $: ", total

    def discount():
        return float(total*0.15)
    disc = discount()
    disc2=0
    if total > 150:
        print "<p>Discount: $" , float(disc),"</p>"
    else:
        total<150
        print "<p>Discount:" ,disc2,"</p>"

    g1 = int(form["quantity"].value)
    g2 = int(form["quantity2"].value)
    g3 = int(form["quantity3"].value)
    g4 = int(form["quantity4"].value)
    g5 = int(form["quantity5"].value)

    def gift():
        return g1+g2+g3+g4+g5 
    giftwrp = gift()
    if form.getvalue("giftwrap"):
        print "<p>Gift wrap cost: $ ",int(giftwrp),".00</p>"

    b1 = form["customerProv"].value


    total = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5

    if total > 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
        print"<p>Tax: $",(total-disc)*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total <150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
        print "<p>Tax: $",total*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total > 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
        print "<p>Tax: $",float(((total-disc)+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total < 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
        print "<p>Tax: $",float((total+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total > 150 and b1 != "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC":
        print"<p>Tax: $",float((total-disc))*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total < 150 and b1!= "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC":
        print "<p>Tax: $",float(total)*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total > 150 and b1 != "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC" and form.getvalue("giftwrap"):
        print "<p>Tax: $",float(((total-disc)+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>"
    elif total < 150 and b1 != "BC" or b1 != "bc" or b1 != "Bc" or b1 != "bC" and form.getvalue("giftwrap"):
        print "<p>Tax: $",float((total+giftwrp))*0.12,"</p>"


    print "</body></html>"
```

Comment: After rereading this carefully, it looks like your actual question is "Can someone have a look at them?" So the answer is "Yes". If you have an a different question, you need to tell us what it is. Is the `if` statement doing something different than what you expected? OK, then what did you expect it to do? Can you give us a couple of simple cases with input (the set of values for `total`, `b1`, and everything else you think might be relevant), expected result (like "the if part should execute"), and actual result (like "but it doesn't")? Even better, strip it down to a one-liner.

Comment: You need to say what a "correct answer" looks like. We're not mind-readers.

Comment: As a side note, what are all those `float(…)` supposed to be accomplishing? If you're adding two `float` values, you get a `float`. If you're adding two `int` values, you get an `int`, but multiplying that by `0.12` will give you a `float` anyway. If you've got strings or something, then adding them and calling `float` on the result won't do anything useful—`float("10"+"20")` is the same as `float("1020")`, which is `1020.0`, not `30.0`. This _could_ be useful if they're, say, `decimal.Decimal` values, but I suspect they aren't.

Comment: What I am trying to ask: lets say the first if statements says: if total <150 and nd (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC"): this should take the total purchases and times it by 0.12. It does this but doesn't give me the correct answer.
The second on if total > 150 and (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC"): print "(total-disc)*0.12" becuase discount is applied if the purchase is above $150. I want the if statement to subtract the total from the discount and then calculate its tax –

Comment: and for the last few where it mentions form.getvalue("giftwrap", this option is for giftwrapping, if the user selects this option, gift wrapping is to be  added on the total amount after its been discounted. I am not even sure if that's the correct way of putting that there

Comment: @user3743933: Don't put comments trying to explain how to read your question; edit your question so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of the `or` operator is lower than the precedence of `and`. This means that the expression

```
if total > 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
```

is evaluated as

```
if (total > 150 and b1 == "BC") or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC":
```

You probably want instead

```
if total > 150 and (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC"):
```

that can also be written in a more readable form as

```
if total > 150 and b1.lower() == "bc":
```

Comment: Ok lets say the first if statements says: if total <150 and nd (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC"): this should take the total purchases and times it by 0.12. It does this but doesn't giv me the correct answer

Comment: and the second on if total > 150 and  (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 == "bC"): print "(total-disc)*0.12" becuase discount is applied if the purchase is above $150. I want the if statement to subtract the total from the discount and then calculate its tax

Comment: and for the last few where it mentions form.getvalue("giftwrap", this option is for giftwrapping, if the user selects this option, gift wrapping is to be added on the total amount after its been discounted. I am not even sure if thats the correct way of putting that there

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you consider "correct answers", how can anyone tell you why they're not doing what you expect? They're certainly doing what you've written, so we have to make a wild guess at what you don't understand.

My wild guess is that you don't understand precedence between `and` and `or`, so you're expecting this:

```
if total > 150 and b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or …:
```

… to mean this:

```
if total > 150 and (b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or …):
```

But actually, it means this:

```
if (total > 150 and b1 == "BC") or b1 == "bc" or …:
```

Whenever you have a precedence problem, try breaking it down into pieces, then you can figure out which pieces might need parentheses, and add them, and then build the big expression back up.

Comment: it still doesn't give me the correct answer when i typing something else than those combinations and my answers seem to be incorrect

Comment: @user3743933: Since you still haven't told us what the correct answer is and what it's doing differently, I'm not surprised that my wild guess isn't exactly what you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of trying to compare for every combination of upper or lowercase characters for a given string, a simple trick is to instead just lowercase the string and compare it to the lowercase of the value you wish to match.

  i.e, instead of `b1 == "BC" or b1 == "bc" or b1 == "Bc" or b1 =="bC"`

  simply use `b1.lower() == "bc"`
- What if `total == 150`? You don't seem to have a case for this.
- Instead of so many `elif`s, separate it into four cases

Like so:

```
if b1.lower() == "bc":
    if total > 150:
        # 1st case, is bc and total > 150
    else:
        # 2nd case, is bc and total <= 150
else:
    if total > 150:
        # 3rd case, is not bc and total > 150
    else:
        # 4th case, is not bc and total <= 150
```

Comment: These are good comments, but they don't do anything to answer the question.

Comment: To be fair, the question hardly gives any indication what an answer should look like. What exactly is a "correct answer"? OP has given little to no context.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in a comment, I think the only correct answer to the question as written is, "Yes, someone can take a look at it." Or maybe "Yes, I took a look at it. Looks like a bunch of Python code. Good for you." So, taken literally, your answer is as good as any. But practically, it's hard to imagine any reasonable-for-SO question that this would be the answer to; these are just a couple of comments for how to make his code more readable.

Comment: @abarnert I guess I'm merely hoping that rewriting it with clear code paths will lead to whichever the correct business logic OP wants, correcting itself naturally; or OP being able to spot their own error more easily.